# file-name replace using options in Linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, scripting, find

I am using the below command to replace the file names in `/opt/jboss/QueueStandalone/cron` folder all `.sh` files:

```
find /opt/jboss/QueueStandalone/cron -name '*.sh' -exec sed -i -e 's/Old-name/New-name/g' {} \;
```

My query is I am palling to build a shell script like it need to take a backup file all `.sh` files then using the options like

```
Old-name=
New-name=
```

If I enter the both values using script it need to be change in all `.sh` files.

Answer (score 0):

Shell variable names must not contain a dash.

```
old_name="foo"
new_name="bar"
sed -i -e "s/${old_name}/${new_name}/g"
```

But make sure that the old and the new name do not contain anything that would be interpreted by `sed` (like a dot...). Or you would have to escape these chars:

```
old_name="foo\.sh"
new_name="bar.sh"
```

But the whole approach seems very strange to me. Usually you would pass parameters to a script and call it like

```
/path/to/script "$old_name" "$new_name"
```

or

```
OLD_NAME=foo NEW_NAME=bar /path/to/script
```